# How to permanently edit the core_pattern file?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, apport

I am trying to locate my coredump file in ubuntu `12.04` LTS but I cant. The problem is that I have to edit the `core_pattern` file content after every reboot to get it, because apport doesn't work (don't know why).

Is there any way to permanently set `core_pattern` file's content??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` configuration setting is set when the `apport` crash reporting service starts on system boot.  So the first step in the process would be to disable `apport`.  This can be done by editing the `/etc/default/apport` file, and setting `enabled=0`.

At this point, the kernel default core pattern should remain on boot.  If you want to switch to some other pattern you can do this by placing a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` that ends in `.conf` (e.g. 60-core-pattern.conf).  It's contents should look something like this (adjusting for your desired pattern):

```
kernel.core_pattern = core
```

That should cause your custom pattern to be loaded on boot.  You should be able to test it without rebooting by running `sudo sysctl --system`.

Comment: Everything was fine for the whole process except for the last part "sudo sysctl --system" as it displayed '--system' as unknown parameter. After consulting sysctl manual I alternatively used "sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/60-core-pattern.conf" command to execute sysctl using the recently created file. Then I got the coredump file in the /var/crash/ directory. Thank you sir.

Comment: Ah.  I guess the `--system` option was added after 12.04.